# PostgreSQL. Symfony. Посоветуйте аналог PHPmyAdmin

Tags: postgresql, symfony

Начал активную работу с `PostgreSQL` на `Symfony` (если это важно). И без "полезностей" по типу `PhpMyAdmin` просто невыносимо. Посоветуйте что-то актуальное\современное.

Спасибо!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[phpPgAdmin](http://phppgadmin.sourceforge.net/doku.php) Вам в помощь. Также [вот тут](http://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/Community_Guide_to_PostgreSQL_GUI_Tools) можно найти что угодно на свой вкус. Я лично OmniDB предпочитаю для PostgreSQL. Но он не вебный. Если нужен именно вебный, то в принципе [Adminer](https://www.adminer.org/) весьма удобная вещь, да ещё и универсальная к тому же.